# Custom sort of results

Tags: entity-framework, linq

If an entity say blog has a string field called Title, how could I force all the records that have a specific value, eg.  where Blog.Title == "Freds Blog" to be at the top of the results - rather than an alphabetic order sort (sorting by the field name)

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var blogs = context.Blogs.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order descending by boolean condition first.

```cs
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Title == "Freds Blog")
    .ThenBy(b => b.Id) // or other fields
    .ToList();
```